# Can a Pact of the Chain Warlock have a celestial imp as a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

*Pact of the Chain* says (bold text mine):

> You learn the *find familiar* spell and can cast it (...)
>
> When you cast the spell, (...) choose one of the following special **forms: imp**, pseudodragon, quasit, sprite

The *Find Familiar* spell says:

> You gain the service of (...) a spirit (...), the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form though it is a celestial, fiend or fey **(your choice)**
>
> If you cast this spell while you have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form. (...) Your familiar transforms into the new creature.

Can a Pact of the Chain Warlock that has a celestial familiar cast the spell again and have assume the imp shape? Would it be considered a celestial?

Answer (score 17):

## Yes and yes.

It is all in the wording of the spell and feature.

> it is a celestial, fiend or fey (your choice)

Implies that you have a familiar and pick what it is, regardless of its form.

> If you cast this spell while you have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form.

Implies your familiar just changes form, but remains being what it is (e.g., Celestial).

> choose one of the following special forms

Implies you have access to new forms.

So, yes, **the familiar can take the imp shape**, and **it is still a celestial** (assuming your previous familiar was one.