# Find Familiar magical item

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, balance, crafting

I want help to create a magic item.  I am a Bard 1/Sorcerer 2 with a (Faerie Dragon) pet. I would like to make an item in-game. I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

I want an item (or a set? Like when you need to wear a pair of boots for them to activate a magical effect) so that I could make this pet of mine into a familiar - I'd like to be able to see through their eyes and cast spells through them as well.

Probably attunement would be required because I would not like it so that someone else could "use" my pet as their familiar.  I would like help in the way of making them cost-wise balanced and about their rarity (which could influence their cost).

I would not need the ability to respawn my familiar, I don't think (even though it would be nice), but I would definitely not need to be able to change their form.  Maybe just increase the distance from which we can talk telepathically?

P.S.:

- [Here is the link](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) for the original spell as a reference
- [Here is the link](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17108-faerie-dragon-older) for the pet stats block

Comment: If you’ve already got a home brewed magic item and need help tweaking it for balance or something like that, we can probably handle that, but we don’t do “homebrew this for me” questions.

Comment: I see. I'll ask my DM and make a draft. If I edit my question then, can you then help us to review it so it is not unbalanced?

Comment: Yeah, that’s probably something we can do. See [this meta question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question) for guidance writing homebrew review questions.

Comment: Related: [Familiars without casting Find Familiar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198640/75095).

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Am I missing something here? This seems like a pretty straightforward idea generation or “homebrew this for me” sort of question, which we have always closed as opinion based.

Comment: @ThomasMarkovisonStrike They want a Faery Dragon familiar. Item is just the cludgy solution they came up with. A DM allowing such an item (at the cost of an attunement slot) could also allow using a FD like a Pseudodragon. Without a cost, I think its a little OP. I thought it would be useful to them to understand the alternative ways to get unusual familiars without even needing an item.